# Transmit Linux script arguments to a python script with arguments

Tags: python, linux, shell, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am not a regular user of Linux shell script and I have one which calls a Python script. I want to add different optional arguments when I run the shell script and transmit it to a certain Python script.

```
while getopts r:d: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        r) include_r_filter=${OPTARG};;
        d) include_d_members=${OPTARG};;
        \?) # Invalid option
            echo "Error: Invalid option"
            exit;;
    esac
done

PARAM_RGR="-rgr " 
PARAM_RGR+=$include_r_filter
PARAM_WD="-wd "
PARAM_WD+=$include_d_members

source ../devEnv/bin/activate && printf "*** devEnv activated\n\n"

printf "***** runing first_py\n" && python3 ./first_py.py && printf "*** first_py done\n\n" \
&& printf "***** runing second_py\n" && python3 ./second_py.py PARAM_RGR PARAM_WD && printf "*** second_py done\n\n" \
&& printf "***** runing third_py\n" && python3 ./third_py.py PARAM_RGR && printf "*** third_py done\n\n"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you encountered, what happens, and what you want to happen instead, etc?

Comment: When I run in the shell : "myscript -r True -d False", the python scripts are run with default values, non with the values in arguments of my command line